# How can I create a bounty of 25 points?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to set a bounty of 25 points. 100 is too much.

Comment: 25 isn't possible, 100 is too much, 50 sounds about right.

Comment: Also, sometimes you will see 25 points rewarded as a result of a bounty which was offered for 50 points and never awarded by the user offering, but where there was an answer qualifying for the bounty. The 25 points is awarded from the community user as half of the posted bounty.

Comment: @Travis 100 ***isn't*** much :)

Comment: Did you post an answer on that question? Previously put a bounty on it? Those can raise the requirement to 100.

Comment: @nicael - I think you have an interesting outlook on bounties and their relation to reputation, you probably have offered the most total reputation in bounties across the entire exchange :)

Comment: @Brad Are you kidding? I am not *even close* to be the top bountier in the SE network :D (burned 16,650 reps netowk wide)

Comment: By default, questions have a bounty of 15 points (when you accept it as the right answer). In addition, you can award an extra 10 points by upvoting it (giving the answerer a total of 25 points). This is free from any spending on the part of the asker.

Comment: @Pluto That's not really a bounty; that's just reputation. (I think I see what you're saying, though – that's an easy way to award 25 rep.)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes I put an answer on it, but I don't think it's the best answer.

Comment: Well, that would explain it then. Thats the rules ("to avoid overly promotional bounties").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The minimal amount is 50, unless you have already started a bounty of 50 reps (min amount doubles each time) or have an answer there (min is 100 in this case). If you don't award it manually *and* don't accept any answer *and* an answer was posted after you started the bounty *and* reached the score of 2, the Community would award half-amount - 25 in case you spend 50 reps on this bounty.

Comment: The requirement jumps to 100 (or more) if you previously put a bounty on the question or have an answer posted on it.

Comment: The minimum was 100 points.